# In Typescript, can I create a mapped type that forces properties to be required?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

In Typescript, we have mapped types that can map properties from one type to another.

A common example is the Partial type, which makes all properties on the generic type 'optional'.

I would like to achieve the opposite, something like Required, where all properties are made 'required', regardless of their optionality up front.

> Is such a thing possible?

(Since learned my question is superficial, please see update!)

**Update:**

Some context...

I'm learning about mapped types, and was inspired by the documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

```
type Proxy<T> = {
    get(): T;
    set(value: T): void;
}
type Proxify<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Proxy<T[P]>;
}
function proxify<T>(o: T): Proxify<T> {
   // ... wrap proxies ...
}
let proxyProps = proxify(props);
```

I thought to myself, hmm, "I wonder what mischief we can get up to with this?"

So I wrote something like:

```
type ProxyObservable<T> = Observable<T> & {
  [P in keyof T]: ProxyObservable<T[P]>;
};
```

Which is cool, because you can give it a type like this:

```
  interface Foo {
    myNum: number;
    myString: string;
    myObject: {
      someValue: number;
      anotherValue: Date;
    };
  }
```

And you get a `ProxyObservable<Foo>` type where every property is Observable of the same type, but also has matching navigation properties for child properties (which are also Observable).

```
const foo: ProxyObservable<Foo> = Proxify<Foo>(...)
foo.myNum.subscribe(...)
foo.myObject.subscribe(...)
foo.myObject.someValue.subscribe(...)
```

Unholy, I know. But cool.

The interesting problem comes in when you make a property (such as myObject) optional. Then Typescript will break on:

```
foo.myObject.someValue.subscribe(...)
```

Because it can't discern whether the type to union with Observable is 'undefined' or the object we defined. This is where my question came in.

BUT... I now also see that this isn't a problem with 'optional' properties, so much a problem with Discriminated Union types in general.

I realised that given the right context, Typescript may be able to infer the type of the `foo.myObject` property. I tried a few variations:

```
foo.myObject!.someValue //<- Nope
foo.myObject ? foo.myObject.someValue : ... //<- Nope
if(foo.myObject) foo.myObject.someValue //<- Nope
```

In my mind the Typescript compiler should be able to infer this!

Can anyone tell me why not?

Answer (score 6):

This is now possible and built into TypeScript as the `Required` type as of TypeScript 2.8.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

Here's the definition of it:

```
/**
 * Make all properties in T required
 */
type Required<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: T[P];
};
```

Comment: This does not convert sub/nested properties from optional to required. How would one do that?

Answer (score 3):

Type operators aren't powerful enough to do this as of yet, as @MeirionHughes says.

Why do you want this?  One thing you *can* do is use [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) is to make a function which accepts a `Partial<T>` and returns a `T`.  This actually works at the type level, but it's essentially impossible to actually *implement* such a function, since it would need to be able to take, say, and empty object at runtime, and magically know what properties to add to it.  Can't be done.  But anyway, here's the declaration:

```
declare function unpartial<T>(t: Partial<T>): T;
```

Say you have a *concrete* type with some optional and some required properties:

```
interface Stuff {
  foo?: string;
  bar?: number;
  baz: boolean;
  qux: () => void; 
}
```

If you had the `unpartial()` function and an instance of `Stuff` you could call it and get an object of the desired type:

```
declare const stuff: Stuff;
const unpartialStuff = unpartial(stuff);
type UnpartialStuff = typeof unpartialStuff;
// UnpartialStuff = { 
//  foo: string; 
//  bar: number; 
//  baz: boolean; 
//  qux: () => void;
// }
```

This is great but does not-great things at runtime, since `unpartial` is just declared but not implemented.  You can have your cake and sort-of eat it too by doing this:

```
const unpartialStuff = (true as false) || unpartial(null! as Stuff);
type UnpartialStuff = typeof unpartialStuff;
```

That `(true as false)` evaluates at runtime to `true` but is interpreted by the type system as `false`, meaning that at runtime `unpartial()` never gets called but the compiler thinks it does and evaluates the types for you.  And since we are lying to the compiler anyway, we might as well not waste a variable name on the fake instance of `Stuff`; hence `(null! as Stuff)`.

Let's put that all in one place:

```
declare function unpartial<T>(t: Partial<T>): T;
interface Stuff {
  foo?: string;
  bar?: number;
  baz: boolean;
  qux: () => void; 
}
const unpartialStuff = (true as false) || unpartial(null! as Stuff);
type UnpartialStuff = typeof unpartialStuff;
```

There you go, you've lied and cheated to fool the compiler to calculate `UnpartialStuff` from `Stuff`.  It's up to you if this trickery is worth it in your case.  Good luck!

---

#### Update

> Can anyone tell me why not?

Well, the reason why it doesn't work is that `keyof (A | B)` = `(keyof A) & (keyof B)`, so `keyof (A | undefined)` = `(keyof A) & never` = `never`.  So as soon as you try to map over the keys of a possibly-`undefined` type you find that there are no keys.

This identity, where the keys of a union are the *intersection* of the keys of each constituent, is the "safe" identity, since the only keys you know exist on a union are the keys that exist in every constituent.  That is [working as intended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12948).

For mapping over the keys of unions, you'd need some unsafe operation, or conditional mapped types or other type operator so you could map over each constituent.  And unfortunately those type operators don't currently exist in TypeScript.

I'm not sure how best to proceed.  Recursive mapped types without more powerful type operations are really limited, and you've hit one of those limits. Maybe someone has better suggestions, other than "wait for future TypeScript features".  Good luck again!

Comment: This is both beautiful and unholy, thanks for taking the time to write it up. Out of academic interest, I updated my post with some better context for my question! I'd be v. happy if you'd take a look!

Comment: I posted an update but I don't have any solution, just an explanation for what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do it generically with a type map. (Happy to be proven wrong and I'll delete this answer if so). There is an issue for [this very question on github too](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15012), but some of the proposed solutions don't work for me.

To do it generically, I think you'd need type subtraction, [which is still being discussed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183). You'd use the subtraction to 'remove' `undefined` from the type union `T | undefined`.

The only way I know of "forcing" certain properties to be there, on the back of something partial, is to use a union with explicitly known properties:

```
interface Foo {
  a: number;
}

let a: Partial<Foo> & { a: number } = {}
```

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; }'.
>       Property 'a' is missing in type '{}'.

An example:

```
class Person {
  id: string;
  name: string = "John";
  address: string = "empty";

  constructor(init: Partial<Person> & { id: string }) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}   

let person = new Person({ id: "1234" });
```

where you force the id to be there, but everything else is partial.

Comment: Thanks for the link to type subtraction, I'm glad to see it's on the roadmap. What an interesting feature!

Also, I think this is a really interesting technique to override certain properties, unfortunately I don't know specific property definitions up front.

I also posted some extra context and an update to my question, I'd be very happy if you had time to take a look.