# How to force class to implement properties that can store undefined value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I'm trying to create a mapped type that would force a class to implement a set of properties based on some object type. Basically when object type is extended, class needs to be extended as well.

```js
type SomeObjectType = {
    a?: {/* ... */},
    b?: {/* ... */},
    c?: {/* ... */}
}

type SomeMappedType = {
    [K in keyof SomeObjectType]: SomeGenericClass<K>
}

class SomeClass implements SomeMappedType {
  a?: SomeGenericClass<'a'>;
  b?: SomeGenericClass<'b'>;
  c?: SomeGenericClass<'c'>;
}
```

The issue with the above code is, that since all object properties in `SomeObjectType` are optional `?` it doesn't force the class to implement them.

I tried to use `| undefined` but it doesn't work either. Only way to make it work is to get rid of `?` using `-?`:

```js
type SomeMappedType = {
    [K in keyof SomeObjectType]-?: SomeGenericClass<K>
}

class SomeClass implements SomeMappedType {
  a: SomeGenericClass<'a'>;
  b: SomeGenericClass<'b'>;
  c: SomeGenericClass<'c'>;
}
```

But then I can't store `undefined` values to those properties.

Comment: if you do `class SomeClass implements SomeType`, TypeScript will complain if a,b or c are missing. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @TobiasS. Yes, It is what I want. But from what I saw, it didn't work that way in my case.

Comment: @TobiasS. Here is my real code example: https://github.com/jamacku/plumber/blob/55da4ea1ac5d57eb29b15c8e6176f67526d64120/src/models/config/rules/rules.model.ts

Comment: @TobiasS. You were right, thank you! Issue with my code is that all properties in the object can be `undefined` so I'm forced to use `-?` in my mapped type in order to achieve expected behavior. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53834559/10221282) But then I'm not able to assign undefined to those properties.

Comment: you can assign `undefined` to it, if you make the property optional `blocking?: boolean` in the class where you implement `RulesProperties`

Comment: @TobiasS. Could you please provide me with some example? I'm not sure what you mean by your last suggestion. Thank you. Also I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need? I used `Array` for demonstration purposes.

```
type SomeObjectType = {
    a: {/* ... */},
    b?: {/* ... */},
    c?: {/* ... */}
}

type RequiredLiteralKeys<T> = keyof { [K in keyof T as string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never :
    {} extends Pick<T, K> ? never : K]: 0 }

type OptionalLiteralKeys<T> = keyof { [K in keyof T as string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never :
    {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never]: 0 }

type SomeMappedType = {
  [K in RequiredLiteralKeys<SomeObjectType>]: Array<K>
} & {
  [K in OptionalLiteralKeys<SomeObjectType>]-?: Array<K> | undefined
}

class SomeClass implements SomeMappedType {
  a!: Array<'a'>;
  b!: Array<'b'>;
  c!: undefined // will error if c is missing but undefined still works
}
```

All required properties stay required and all optional will be converted to `Array<T> | undefined`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgeQEYCsIGNgBVzQC8UA3gLABQU1UAhgFykD0AVFAHSdQtMC%20ANJRpRUAfkYlWHLjwFCaWcczad23PpV6VKoSFABKEAI4BXAJYAnCABMAMmeAQLtADYBpCCADOAHlwA%20KGIAa084ADNSKABtNygzADsoUJAIqFw6LygvYAtEgHMoCAAPRwTrLLjRKASIADcnKEYEkwRURpKyiqgqmvrG%20nlqEl4i0ohyrIAFMyxgv34ewOrahosmnoBdRgAGKC0KHQIoZDBgMzgE13tHZ3dPXwCg5LDIkhi4xJfUyIzaLJyeQShU6E26vVWAxqrXa61Bkx6UBW-XWgyoNBGYy601m81wizcy0RzRR2ygewORz08CQAFlaGBINZ8HpiOR0bF4klDKZLDYbk5XB5vD4aSgMNg8AR-GSAIIWZwgHyEzRQABkpHknK%20p3Ol2uDkF9xFYrQmBwLIgMoAtEp5YrlYEAD5QEzlCDhRI2TTaChYFz-LJigDCAa8WTMCDALggSASwCDiAg9MZNktmvRtAAhIx7bQlQByWgF-wAbnkqBzUDzhdQJfL6KwVbd1g9XusmiAA)

Comment: Thank you so much, It works perfectly. Could you please add some notes about `RequiredLiteralKeys` and `OptionalLiteralKeys` types, I'm a bit confused about what they do. Thank you.

Comment: They get all required and all optional keys respectively. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52991061/8613630

Answer (score 1):

Non-optional properties (no ?) must be defined, but through a type union we can specify that they are a specified type or undefined.

```
interface MandatoryFoo {
  bar: string | undefined
  baz: string | undefined
}

const x: MandatoryFoo = { bar: undefined, baz: undefined }
```

Optional properties (with ?) can be omitted.

```
interface OptionalFoo {
  bar?: string | undefined
  baz?: string | undefined
}

const y: OptionalFoo = { bar: undefined }
```

Optional properties inherently permit undefined, so we don't actually need the union type.  You can specify the property as undefined or omit it.

```
interface OptionalShorthandFoo {
  bar?: string
  baz?: string
}

const z: OptionalShorthandFoo = { bar: undefined }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJxAEzmA9lATwDFddkBvAKGWQCM4oAuZAZzClAHNkAfZAVywQYoCJmp04AL2ZsOIbn0GZho8QF9KlBLhBtkAD2bosOfMVLIAvBUlMBQkSDEAaSTIcqnY5JsqhIWEQUAHkABzBgXTgAGxIyKhp6KAB+WXYuXk9VZ3Ek6TTWDIUs5RyxSj8dPTBkAmZwyOi4yxtyO2Yy70xfLQDoeCRkRqiQWIBlAAt8MEmMTHiKCWTCuS5lgvT5Tkqtav0PEeapmbmsRbaO7O7erSA)